# Opening files in a directory with opendir and readdir in C

Tags: c

When I try to open a directory and traverse through its files, I do not get the individual files upon every call of readdir. This is my code:

```
Plugin* load_plugins(char * plugName) {
    char ** pluginPaths = getPluginPaths();
    Plugin ** plugins = malloc(0);
    //char* env = getenv("PLUGIN_DIR");
    DIR* dir = opendir("./plugins/"); //opens the directory specifying the available plugins

    struct dirent* dr = readdir(dir);
    int i = 0;
    while ((dr = readdir(dir))) {
        i++;
        //everytime we add a plugin we allocate more space
        plugins = realloc(plugins, i * sizeof(Plugin));
        void *handle = dlopen(strcat("./plugins/", dr->d_name), RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!handle) { exit(1); }
        //do some stuff with the plugin here
    }
    
    return plugins;
}
```

What could be wrong? The first call of readdir returns a dirent* with d_name:
[the dirent struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oajw.png)

Comment: Your code is cut off. Where's the end of the loop.

Comment: Yea, the rest of the loop isnt too important. It is just that at the first initialization of dr the error occurs.

Comment: `strcat("./plugins/", dr->d_name)` I'm surprised that doesn't crash, but that's undefined behavior for you.

Comment: What error are you seeing? You really don't give us much information to go on!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the issue is in code that you have not shown us.
Here's a basic, working example of looping through the files in a given (hard-coded) directory. You should be able to adapt this to do what you need.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  DIR* dir = opendir(".");
  if (!dir)
  {
    perror("opendir");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  struct dirent* dr;
  while ((dr = readdir(dir)))
  {
    printf("%s\n", dr->d_name);
  }
  closedir(dir);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

**Update**
I've to log off for the evening but based on your updated code, here's an updated template. The comments explain the bits that were missing or problematic in your code. Hopefully this is enough for you figure out what's going wrong.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Dummy Plugin -- replace with real one */
typedef struct _Plugin 
{
  char *handle;
} Plugin;

/* Exiting might not be the right thing. Edit as necessary */
void fatal_error(char *message)
{
  perror(message);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* 
 * Your code had no way for the caller to know how many 
 * plugins were found, so I added numPlugins.
 * Both pluginDir and numPlugins must be non-NULL.
 * On error returns NULL.
 */
Plugin* load_plugins(char* pluginDir, int* numPlugins)
{
  /* Up to caller to ensure this is true */
  assert(pluginDir && numPlugins);

  DIR* dir = opendir(pluginDir);
  /* You need to error check the return of opendir */
  if (!dir)
  {
    fatal_error("opendir");
    return NULL;
  }

  struct dirent* dr;
  /* No real point in doing malloc(0) here. */
  Plugin *plugins = NULL;
  int i = 0;
  while ((dr = readdir(dir)))
  {

    /* 
     * You can't strcat into a const string. Not sure how your 
     * code ever worked!
     */
    char *path = malloc(strlen(pluginDir) + strlen(dr->d_name) + 1);
    if (!path)
    {
      /* 
       * Don't forget to clean up -- this probably should be factored out
       * and loop through the elements of plugins freeing any
       * dynamically allocated fields or, for example, calling `dlclose`
       * on handles. In this implementation it will leak the paths,
       * but if `malloc` fails you're (probably) already in a world of
       * hurt!
       */
      free(plugins);
      fatal_error("malloc");
      return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(path, pluginDir);
    strcat(path, dr->d_name);

    i++;
    Plugin* new_plugins = realloc(plugins, i * sizeof(Plugin));
    if (!new_plugins)
    {
      fatal_error("realloc");
      /* see note above about cleaning up. */
      free(plugins);
      return NULL;
    }
    plugins = new_plugins;
    plugins[i - 1].handle = path;
    *numPlugins = i;
  }
  closedir(dir);
  return plugins;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  int nPlugins = 0;
  Plugin* plugins = load_plugins("./", &nPlugins);
  printf("Found %d plugins %p\n", nPlugins, plugins);
  for (int i = 0; i < nPlugins; ++i)
  {
    printf("[%d]: %s\n", i, plugins[i].handle);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Edited to include the rest of the code